# how to get bus id of an usb device

Tags: usb, devices

I would like to bind/unbind my usb device - a wireless adapter.

```
echo -n "1-1:1.0" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/ub/unbind
```

So to able to do that, I need the bus ID. `lsusb` prints out the following:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:2573 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2501/RT2573 Wireless Adapter
```

And `lsusb -t`:

```
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/3p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=smsc95xx, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 4, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=rt73usb, 480
```

So where can I find this bus ID? Thanks!
**Update:**
here is the detailed info about the wireless devide: (`lsusb -v | grep -E '\<(Bus|iProduct|bDeviceClass|bDeviceProtocol)' 2>/dev/null`)

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:2573 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2501/RT2573 Wireless Adapter
  bDeviceClass            0 (Defined at Interface level)
  bDeviceProtocol         0 
  iProduct                2
```

Comment: maybe this will help you: **lsusb -v | grep -E '\<(Bus|iProduct|bDeviceClass|bDeviceProtocol)' 2>/dev/null**

Comment: @LilloX updated the question, can you please help to find that id?

Comment: In you situation: Bus=1, Port=2 so: **echo -n "1-2" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind** You don't need the device number

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As I was grepping for the `productVendor`  I kept thinking this can't be so hard (though inventive)... Might as well RTFM. `man lsusb`:

```
-t, --tree
              Tells lsusb to dump the physical USB device hierarchy as a tree. Verbosity can be increased twice with the v option.
```

...twice. TWICE. `lsusb -tvv`:

```
/:  Bus 06.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=uhci_hcd/2p, 12M
    ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
    /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb6  /dev/bus/usb/006/001
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/6-2  /dev/bus/usb/006/002 <--these guys right here
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
        ID 0bda:8771 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
        /sys/bus/usb/devices/6-2  /dev/bus/usb/006/002
```

Comment: Thanks for that! 

Here is a oneliner with awk to get the deviceId given you know the vendor/product:
`lsusb -tvv | awk '/046d:c52b/ { getline; print gensub(/.*devices\/([0-9\-\.]*)/, "\\1", "g", $1); exit; }'`

Answer (score 19):

You can read off the sequence from the device tree you get with `lsusb -t`. The number before the hyphen is the bus, the numbers after the hyphen are the port sequence. Your device is on bus `01`, on port `1` of the root hub for this bus is another hub, and on port `3` of this hub is your device: So you get `1-1.3`.

If you know the vendor id from `lsusb` (like `148f` for Ralink), you can also `grep` for it with

```
grep 148f /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/idVendor
```

and you'll get something like

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.3/idVendor:148f
```

as answer. If there are several devices from the same vendor, you can narrow it down with `idProduct`.

Comment: Why is it not `1-1.1.3` as those are the port numbers walking down the tree?

Comment: I agree that the recent suggested edit wasn’t very good, but it did highlight the fact that this answer could be improved by expanding on the last sentence.

Answer (score 4):

finally I found the right bus ID of the usb device. There is a file listing all the IDs - `/sys/bus/usb/devices/` and the content is the following:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# ls /sys/bus/usb/devices
1-0:1.0  1-1  1-1.1  1-1:1.0  1-1.1:1.0  1-1.3  1-1.3:1.0  usb1
```

and the corresponding lsusb:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# lsusb -t
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=dwc_otg/1p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/3p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=smsc95xx, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 17, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=rt73usb, 480M

root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9512 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 148f:2573 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2501/RT2573 Wireless Adapter
```

so I tried 1-1.3 as an ID and it worked. But 1-3 did not.

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# echo -n "1-3" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind
bash: echo: write error: No such device
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example where I was trying to do the same thing on Ubuntu 16.04 for USB-Ethernet device:

```
anurag@anurag-ThinkPad-E470:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0424:5744 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
```

We want to unbind the first device. You can see the driver instance created in sysfs and within the driver, an instance of the USB bus address of the Ethernet Dongle:

```
anurag@anurag-ThinkPad-E470:/sys/bus/usb/drivers$ ls
ax88179_178a  btusb  hub  r8188eu  usb  usbfs  usbhid  uvcvideo
anurag@anurag-ThinkPad-E470:/sys/bus/usb/drivers/ax88179_178a$ ls
2-2.2:1.0  bind  module  new_id  remove_id  uevent  unbind
```

If you plug in another dongle of same type, you can now see two devices:

```
anurag@anurag-ThinkPad-E470:/sys/bus/usb/drivers/ax88179_178a$ ls
2-2.1:1.0  2-2.2:1.0  bind  module  new_id  remove_id  uevent  unbind
```

At this point you can see two net devices:

```
anurag@anurag-ThinkPad-E470:~$ ip link show
....
6: enx000ec6cd8d75: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0e:c6:cd:8d:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: enx000ec6cd8d90: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0e:c6:cd:8d:90 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

You can unbind like so:

```
anurag@anurag-ThinkPad-E470:/sys/bus/usb/drivers/ax88179_178a$ sudo sh -c "echo 2-2.2:1.0 > unbind"
[sudo] password for anurag:
anurag@anurag-ThinkPad-E470:/sys/bus/usb/drivers/ax88179_178a$ ls
2-2.1:1.0  bind  module  new_id  remove_id  uevent  unbind
```

And the device will no longer show up in the interface list:

```
anurag@anurag-ThinkPad-E470:~$ ip link show
....
6: enx000ec6cd8d75: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0e:c6:cd:8d:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Note that just issuing `sudo echo 2-2.2:1.0 > unbind` doesn’t work because that only elevates permission for the echo command and not for the redirection. Hence we use temporarily elevated shell. The unbind is writable only by root user.

Answer (score 2):

For me the easiest way to find Bus ID:device ID (nnn:mmm) is with:

```
watch -n 0.5 -d lsusb
```

This wil run `lsusb` every half a second and highlight the differences between runs. Just plug and replug the device and the related device will be highlighted.

```bsh
Bus 001 Device 006 # → Bus ID: 001, Device: ID 006
```

[Reference](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToIdentifyADevice/USB).